# What's that icon (Oneplus one)?

Tags: oneplus-one

does anybody know what's the meaning of that icon ? 
I have a new oneplus one since several days and today this icon appeared in my status bar.

[image]

Comment: Looks like phone in vibration mode! Not sure though. When did it came up?

Comment: My 2 guesses would be Vibrate (as MANI said) or NFC Icon...

Comment: that's indeed vibration mode indeed, confusion came from the fact that sound was not at zero, only sound level of the phone ring ==> vibration mode

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

The icon in question (on the very left of this image) is `Vibration` mode on the One Plus One.

Technically (I guess) it is the 'phone profile' icon, in this case Vibrate.

Comment: It's not the "Vibration" profile: this icon will appear if the ringer has been silenced and virbrate is enabled regardless of whether it was done using the profile feature or simply changing the volume.

Answer (score 1):

OnePlus One owner here!

Yes, the very left icon is the vibrate icon (assuming you are using CM11S and no extra icon packs).