# What does this notification bar icon mean in the HexoLibre theme by Cyanogenmod?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow, notification-icons, user-interface

The icon in the middle it looks like dancing wobbling phone or something. Totally confused. Not using OnePlus. I'm using Cyanogenmod 13's HexoLibre theme.

[image: icons in status bar]

Comment: Looks like the vibrate icon on the OnePlus One... http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/81525/whats-that-icon-oneplus-one/81527

Comment: Yes, it's possibly OnePlus One, and the theme appears to be "Hexo".

Answer (score 0):

It's the vibrate icon. Interesting, Android has two vibrate icons. Turning ringer volume down all the way, you can see the other icon one.

[image: vibrate ringer volume]
[image: icon]

Even more confusing, when it's not down all the way it shows a ringer icon

[image: ringer volume with icon]